# How to merge 2 arrays of equal length into a single dictionary with key:value pairs in Godot?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, merge, godot, gdscript

I have been trying to randomize the values in an ordered array (ex:[0,1,2,3]) in Godot. There is supposed to be a shuffle() method for arrays, but it seems to be broken and always returns "null". I have found a workaround that uses a Fisher-Yates shuffle, but the resulting array is considered "unsorted" by the engine, and therefore when I try to use methods such as bsearch() to find a value by it's position, the results are unreliable at best.

My solution was to create a dictionary, comprised of an array containing the random values I have obtained, merged with a second array of equal length with (sorted) numbers (in numerical order) which I can then use as keys to access specific array positions when needed.

Question made simple...

In GDScript, how would you take 2 arrays..
ex:  ARRAY1 = [0,1,2,3]
     ARRAY2 = [a,b,c,d]

..and merge them to form a dictionary that looks like this:
MergedDictionary = {0:a, 1:b, 2:c, 3:d}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Godot does not support "zip" methodology for merging arrays such as Python does, so I am stuck merging them manually. However... there is little to no documentation about how to do this in GDScript, despite my many hours of searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = ["a", "b", "c"]
var c = {} 

if a.size() == b.size():
    var i = 0
    for element in a:
        c[element] = b[i]
        i += 1
    print("Dictionary c: ", c)
```

If you want to add elements to a dictionary, you can assign values to the keys like existing keys.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding,and I appreciate the help very much.I tried the code, and it works perfectly fort what I need. Thanks again!